# Zoo Visitor Registration Error

Tags: members, error, zoo-visitor, register

I'm using Zoo Visitor and when a user tries to register, they get this error:

> You must be a logged-in member of this site in order to perform this action.

I'm not sure what is causing it...?

Here is my registration form...

```
{exp:zoo_visitor:registration_form class="form form-validate" return="account/register/success"}
<ul>
    <li class="required">
        <label>First Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="cf_member_first_name" value="">
    </li>
    <li class="required">
        <label>Surname</label>
        <input type="text" name="cf_member_surname" value="">
    </li>
    <li class="required">
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" value="">
    </li>
    <li class="required">
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" value="">
    </li>
    <li>
        By clicking Register, you agree to our Terms &amp; Conditions and that you have read our Privacy Policy, including our Cookie Use.
        <input type="hidden" name="cf_member_terms" value="Yes">
        <input type="hidden" name="cf_member_emails_admin" value="Yes">
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register &rarr;">
    </li>
</ul>
{/exp:zoo_visitor:registration_form}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Add-ons --> Modules --> Zoo Visitor --> Troubleshooting, it should be there.

[edit]:

In Add-ons --> Modules --> SafeCracker, always check to see if anonymous registrations are allowed.

Comment: I'm not too sure what you mean... What should be there? Everything on there either says it exists, installed or present?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I thought this would show up there. If I'm not mistaken this means Safecracker isn't setup properly for anonymous entry-submissions. Go to the Safecracker Module, and check if "Allow guests to post entries?" is allowed for your Zoo Visitor channel.

Comment: That worked! Can you post this as an answer? I can then mark it was the best answer then.

Comment: Edited this answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that user is already logged into the CP when they try to register via the Zoo Visitor form on the front-end?

Make sure you are logged out of the CP, or better yet try another browser to complete the registration.

Comment: I was certainly logged out, and I was using Safari (I normally use Chrome) to test register the user when I got the error.